# Get mapper from AuthenticationSuccessHandler

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, jackson, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to return some User data after a successful login in a Spring Boot application.
To do so, I need to serialize my Principal with the Jackson mapper that is already set-up at bootstrap via a factory.

Is there a way to inject it into the authentication handler?

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    UserDetails me = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    /*mapper.writeValue(writer, user); <- how to get the mapper?
    writer.flush();*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr;

Instead of using a `Factory`, make the `ObjectMapper` a Spring bean. That way it can be injected into both Spring *and* Jersey components.

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper mapper() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper;
}
```

---

When you use an HK2 (Jersey's DI framework) `Factory` to create the `ObjectMapper`, the injection is only available to components that are retrieved through the HK2 `ServiceLocator`, which is the HK2 analogue of the Spring `ApplicationContext`.

When you use Spring-Boot with Jersey, how the two interact under the hood, is through the HK2 [spring-bridge](https://hk2.java.net/spring-bridge/). So for example, say the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is registered in the `ApplicationContext`. With the spring-bridge configured, we can also get the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` through the `ServiceLocator`

```
ServiceLocator l = ...
AuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = l.getService(AuthenticationSuccessHandler.class);
```

That should work. If you have the `ObjectMapper` binded through an HK2 `Factory`, and you were to `@Inject` the mapper into the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, it would be injected, when retrieved through the `ServiceLocator`.

That being said, Spring Security doesn't go through HK2, so it never has a chance to get the `ObjectMapper` through HK2. But if you register the mapper as a Spring bean, then Spring can inject it into the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. And the mapper is still available through HK2 `ServiceLocator` (because of the spring-bridge), so you can still use it with Jersey, same way as if it were binded with a `Factory`.